# How to disable Datanucleus warnings in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, log4j, datanucleus

I am trying to disable a specific warning, as it is obnoxiously spamming my console and my dashboard logs:

```
org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils newSCOInstance
WARNING: Creation of backed wrapper for <package.class.field> unsupported,
so trying simple wrapper
```

I have attempted setting log4j to ERROR level on all Datanucleus messages, but to no avail.
Here are my settings for log4j:

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

log4j.category.DataNucleus=ERROR, A1
```

Which leads me to think that these warnings are coming from another logger... any idea how to disable them/filter them out?

---

**EDIT 1**: Here is some more info about the problematic field:
More precisely, it is package.EntityA.field, where field is:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Map<String,EntityB> field;
```

I can't see why this would be classified as a "not totally supported" type.

---

**EDIT 2**: I switched back to java.util.logging, and tried the following:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = WARNING
Datanucleus.level = WARNING
org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.level = OFF
```

The result is still the same. I even tried setting Datanucleus.level to OFF, but all the messages are logged anyway (both in the development console, and in the GAE dashboard logs).
And yes, I properly configured appengine-web.xml to use my logging configuration.

Answer (score -1):

clearly a message of that nature is a sign of a problem, and "package.class.field" is of some not totally supported type. I fail to see how this can be considered "obnoxious".

DataNucleus logs using standard logging packages (*log4j* if it is found in the CLASSPATH, otherwise *java.util.logging*), so if *log4j* is not present then you need to configure *java.util.logging*

Comment: I edited my first post with more information, maybe we can try to fix the warnings instead of filtering them out.

As for the loggers, I've tried both of them, and used different filter levels, but I just can't seem to gain control over the Datanucleus logger.

Comment: A Map is a more recent addition to GAE and is implemented the way it should be (without a "backing store") whereas the original GAE people implemented Sets/Lists using a backing store (which gives no benefit). This results in a log warning with current DataNucleus codebase since any datastore plugin should really just use backing stores for all, or not at all. The only answer is to fix your logging spec if that message is a problem to you. As said we only use standard logging here http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/logging.html

Comment: I switched back to java.util.logging (see my edit above), but it seems like my configuration is ignored. Any tips on how to fix my logging spec?

Comment: The log link I provided *defines* a config file for DataNucleus. You don't seem to use correct case; yes log categories are sensitive ... standard JDK behaviour

Comment: Let me rephrase: what do I need to do to stop logging all messages coming from `org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils` ?